# build jenkins pipeline got an error regarding gradle not found but gardle is present in the jenkins machine

Tags: git, maven, jenkins, groovy, build

pipeline {

```
agent any    

stages{

    stage('Git checkout'){


        steps{

            script{
                
                git branch: 'development', 
            
            }
        }
    }
    
    stage('gradle build'){

        steps{
            
            script{
                dir("cws/ReportRepo/th.cws/thub/mod.cwscommon") {
                sh """
                   ./gradle clean build
                   ./gradle publishToMavenLocal
                """
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

- ./gradle clean build
  /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/mcn/cws/ReportRepo/th.cws/thub/mod.cwscommon@tmp/durable-cc93ddf3/script.sh: 2: ./gradle: not found

gradle is intalled in jenkins machine. when i put gradle command in jenkins machine it starts build but in pipline script it throws error .